# Maven project with JAXB2 plugin does not work without maven clean

Tags: java, maven, jaxb2-maven-plugin

My Maven project with the JAXB2 plugin works without errors if I run

```
mvn clean install
```

but it always fails if I skip the clean and run

```
mvn install
```

In this case the generated classes are not generated again which is correct:

```
[INFO] No changes detected in schema or binding files - skipping JAXB generation.
```

But then I get an compilation error that the generated classes and packages can not be found when the rest of the static Java sources in this Maven project are compiled:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project [...]: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] [...] package [...] does not exist
[ERROR] [... ]cannot find symbol
```

Here is the relevant part of my pom.xml (the rest is only dependencies):

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<executions>                    
    <execution>
        <id>xjc-core</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sources>
                <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/xsd/core</source>
            </sources>
            <packageName>com.example.core</packageName>
            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <!-- ... and more <execution>  -->
</executions>
```

Am I correct that the only solution is to separate the static sources and generated sources into different Maven modules? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in jaxb2-maven-plugin v2.2 https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin/issues/35.
This bug has been fixed in v2.3